# SQL - OutterApply and Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working with a large stored procedure, I'm having trouble with a small portion of it.

When I execute a query on the table im joining, there can be 0, 1 or 2 results. If there are 0 results, I don't really care, my code returns null values, no big deal. If there is 1 result, my code returns the correct values, however, if there are 2 results, I am having trouble selecting the second result.

My code below works until the second OutterApply(the AHM2 stuff). Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The animal ID is identical for both OuterApplys. I just need to return the second result, if there is one, and if it is not the same as the first one.

```
SELECT TOP 1
        AHM.AnimalHerdManagementId, 
        AHM.HerdManagementId, 
        AHM2.AnimalHerdManagementId, 
        AHM2.HerdManagementId, 
        HM.Code AS HerdManagementCode,  
        HM2.Code AS HerdManagementCode2
OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 AHM.AnimalHerdManagementId, AHM.HerdManagementId
            FROM    dbo.AnimalHerdManagement AHM
            WHERE   AHM.AnimalId = A.AnimalId AND ISNULL(AHM.EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveFrom) <= @EffectiveFrom
            ORDER BY AHM.EffectiveFrom DESC
        ) AHM
        LEFT JOIN dbo.HerdManagement HM ON AHM.HerdManagementId = HM.HerdManagementId
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 AHM2.AnimalHerdManagementId, AHM2.HerdManagementId
            FROM    dbo.AnimalHerdManagement AHM2
            WHERE   AHM2.AnimalId = A.AnimalId AND  AHM2.AnimalHerdManagementId != AHM.AnimalHerdManagementId AND ISNULL(AHM2.EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveFrom) <= @EffectiveFrom
            ORDER BY AHM2.EffectiveFrom DESC
        ) AHM2
LEFT JOIN dbo.HerdManagement HM2 ON AHM2.HerdManagementId = HM2.HerdManagementId
```

Comment: I am a bit lazy, so my first effort would be to return two rows instead of trying to return them stuffed into one row.  It has been my experience that turning rows into columns is a PITA.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: It's not unfortunately. I'm just modifying an existing sp. And adding this column. Can really change it, to much is depending on it.

Comment: I figured as much, otherwise you probably wouldn't be doing it this way.  But I did preface that with the fact that I am a bit lazy...  Can you post what results you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can help you with the `OUTER APPLY` but the method of getting the two different values is going to need some help as my solution is a total hack.

First, you don't need to join on the outer apply.  The join is implied.  So you can completely eliminate the join syntax from your query.

Second, AnimalHerdManagement looks/seems like a special table called a Junction Table.  All the data contained in it is contained elsewhere (That it contains completely redundant data is why it's called a special table).  But that is minor.

Finally, here is some example code I threw together that accomplishes what you are after.  The method I am using to retrieve different results on the two outer apply's is a hack, but if you are sure that will always be true, it might work.  I am not able to get a multi-level outer apply to work.

```
    select * from AH_Animal A
outer apply 
(
    select max (HerdManagementID) as HerdMgmtID1 from AH_AnimalHerdManagement HM1 where HM1.AnimalID = A.AnimalID
) as z
outer apply
(
    select min (HerdManagementID) as HerdMgmtID2 from AH_AnimalHerdManagement HM2 where HM2.AnimalID = A.AnimalID
) as zz
```

I hope that helped.  There has to be another solution to this, as this would not work at all if you ever expected 3 results.

Query Results:

[image: Query Results]

Comment: This should work fine, there are business rule that prevent the possibility of having a 3rd result. Thank you..